# How to store and index filename in solr?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am new in solr development environment and have the following data_config file:

```
dataConfig>  
<dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        baseDir="/home/shah/solr/TestIndex" fileName="\.(txt)|(pdf)|(docx)"
        onError="skip"
        recursive="true">
            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />

            <entity
                name="documentImport"
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                format="text">
                <field column="file" name="fileName"/>

            </entity>
    </entity>
    </document>
```

I have included the above field in my schema.xml as:

Also included the import handler in the solrconfig file accordingly.

I have 10 text files i.e. 1abc.txt, 2B.txt.........10B.txt, I want to store these files names in a field fileName as decleared above:

when i execute the import handler , its working well but the fileName field is empty.

your help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: thanks a lot i solved the above problem/// its very simple just put the file name field inside the FileListEntityProcessor. its will index the file name

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot i solved the above problem/// its very simple just put the file name field inside the FileListEntityProcessor. its will index the file name for actual code see [why the tikaEntityProcesor does not index the Text field in the following data-config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420735/why-the-tikaentityprocesor-does-not-index-the-text-field-in-the-following-data-c)